# Narrow down Prometheus query result to specific hostnames

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to generate a memory usage query to display in Grafana 8. Currently, my query is:

`100 * (1 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes[10m])) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes[10m])))`

However, it's showing all registered nodes. I only want `{node_name=~".*admin.*"}`, but I do not know where to place this in the query.

For example, I have another dashboard that just shows `node_load1{node_name=~".*admin.*"}` which works fine.

So where do I place the `{node_name=~".*admin.*"}`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working. I had to understand the placement of labels in PromQL. I found [this documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) on the placement of the labels, and it appears to be working correctly. Feel free to correct me if this isn't right:

```
100 * (1 - ((avg_over_time(node_memory_MemFree_bytes{node_name=~".*admin.*"}[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Cached_bytes{node_name=~".*admin.*"}[10m]) + avg_over_time(node_memory_Buffers_bytes{node_name=~".*admin.*"}[10m])) / avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{node_name=~".*admin.*"}[10m])))
```

Comment: This looks correct. You are filtering the metrics by `node_name` before using it.